# Named ACL Configuration

Tags: cisco, acl, gns3, lab

I started a Named ACL Lab today and my configuration is not quite working.

LAB: http://gns3vault.com/security/named-access-list/

The first task is creating an ACL which blocks users from NSA's L1 to reach HTTPS on CIA's L2.

The addressing is fine and I can ping all interfaces.

---

My Configuration is placed on NSA, different from author's config which places the config on CIA's router. I later configured it the same way as the lab author configured, and it worked.

My configuration:

`NSA#sh access-lists`

`Extended IP access list NSA_L1_TO_CIA_L2
    10 deny tcp 33.33.33.0 0.0.0.255 111.111.111.96 0.0.0.31 eq 443
    20 permit ip any any (444 matches)`

`sh ip int e0/0
Ethernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up
  Internet address is 192.168.13.3/24
  Broadcast address is 255.255.255.255
  Address determined by setup command
  MTU is 1500 bytes
  Helper address is not set
  Directed broadcast forwarding is disabled
  Multicast reserved groups joined: 224.0.0.5 224.0.0.6
  Outgoing access list is NSA_L1_TO_CIA_L2
  Inbound  access list is NSA_L1_TO_CIA_L2 (This shouldn't be here, I just put for test purposes)
  ... (Continues...)`

---

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

ACL placement is important, and the ACL design is dependent on whether it is inbound or outbound.

The general rule for ACL placement is that extended ACLs should be placed as close to the traffic source as possible, and standard ACLs should be placed as close to the traffic destination as possible. If you think about the contents of the ACLs and how they work, this makes sense.

Changing the location or direction of the ACL is something that you normally don't want to do without changing the ACL itself.